# Grails: Any common file for configuration which is accessible to all Config.groovy, BuildConfig.groovy and DataSource.groovy

Tags: grails, config

I am developing a project which contains multiple projects integrated as Plugin-projects. Through this project I am catering multiple clients who actually need different sets of projects and functionalities. So every time when I need to create a build for a client I need to go into these 3 files to do the following:

1. `Config.groovy` - I have defined multiple global variables of functionalities containing boolean values, which I access in project and hence provide/limit the functionalities to a certain client.
2. `BuildConfig.groovy` - I need to import or comment out the required plugin project via `grails.plugin.location.'XYZProject' = "../XYZProject"`
3. `DataSource.groovy` - Since we are presently using 1 postgre installation to serve more than 100 customers so each one has a separate DB for him. So each time I need to come to this file to change the URL of the DB.

So, I want (if possible), a common place where I can define the global variables which can be accessed by all 3 files mentioned above and I want to check the customer and apply the needed rules.

It will save a lot of time and effort needed to do all this and also will reduce the chance of errors.

Note: I have checked that on creating Global variable in any one of these three files cannot be accessed in the other 2 files.

Answer (score 0):

Data source and config can be [incorporated](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/kchat/blob/master/grails-app/conf/kchatConfig.groovy) but Buildconfig is delicate and not like those two. You may need to write a script that updates the BuildConfig for each build accordingly.